# Using modular JAXB compilation does not (seem to) work when location is not an URL

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have 2 schemas: `a.xsd` and `b.xsd` which has a dependency on `a.xsd` (episode).

Schemas are split in different maven projects and packages.

Originally, `b.xsd` imports `a.xsd` like this (I don't want to change it):

```
<import namespace="urn:a" schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
```

What do I need to put in my `catalog.cat` to translate `a.xsd` to `maven:com.mycompany:a:jar::!/com/mycompany/a/a.xsd`

I tried PUBLIC, SYSTEM, URI, REWRITE_URI, REWRITE_SYSTEM but nothing is working.

As soon as I change the reference `a.xsd` to `http://.../a.xsd` in my schema and use REWRITE_SYSTEM in my catalog, then it is working. But as I said, I don't want to modify my schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems to work with SYSTEM_SUFFIX.

Answer (score 0):

See [Modular Schema Compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Modular-Schema-Compilation), starting with

> However there's a [bug in JAXB/XJC](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-942) this does not work if you have schemaLocation in your `xs:import`.

Resolving schemas in XJC is quite buggy and I did not see any progress on that in the last few years.

So what works for me quite well in a [number](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) [of](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas) [projects](https://github.com/highsource/inspire-schemas):

Compile you schemas not from the local path but some absolute URL. This does not need to actually exist, can be completely virtual. Just use an absolute URL:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsAll.xsd</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
                <!-- ... -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Use a catalog file to rewrite your absolute URL prefix to some local path or resource in a JAR:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net" "maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc"
```

Apply your bindings not to local files but via absolute URLs:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsAll.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="net.opengis.ows.v_2_0"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Thus all your URLs will be absolute (without the need to patch the schemas) and so `REWRITE_SYSTEM` will work as desired. This is the best option I've found so far, and, believe me, I've compiled a lot of schemas.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Comment: On the page [Modular Schema Compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Modular-Schema-Compilation), the link to the Oracle pull request doesn't work, can you fix it please so we can see the status.

Comment: In the meanwhile. somehow using SYSTEM_SUFFIX in my catalog file as described in the above answer, resolves my issue. I was able to compile and generate sources for project B in your example. In our case, we get the contracts from a 3rd party who includes project A.xsd inside B.xsd as below, and unfortunately, I cannot change it.    `<xs:import namespace="http://www.mytestsite.com/Data/1.0" schemaLocation="A.xsd"/> `   Just curious to know if this is OK to use as you haven't recommended using this option in any of your answers?